# About myeclipse.when i upload some files.it't can work on the web page

Tags: java, myeclipse

I want to play videos after people upload some videos, so these files must put into my the path of web's project, but it can't play right now, I must refresh my project.it can be work.so is there some suggestions to solve it?

I use myeclipse 2016. the path like

[image]

Comment: Your question needs to be edited as it isn't clear enough.

Comment: the front page can upload,the uploaded files is stored in the path of WebRoot,like images showing. But when I upload files,I must refresh myeclipse,it can be used by the front page.

Answer (score 0):

Any files added to the project source via an external source (that is, not though functions of MyEclipse, or other eclipse plug-ins) will require a refresh of the project folder, to be seen by eclipse. However, this doesn't affect a deployed web application, running on a server, since MyEclipse/eclipse isn't involved there.

Comment: thanks first! So if I add files to my web project,I must refresh myeclipse.don't I?

Comment: Not always. As I mention, if the file is added to the project through MyEclipse or eclipse functions, then there should be no need to refresh. If the file is added to a project otherwise then the project needs to be refreshed (either PF5 or right click on the project and select Refresh).

Comment: I see,but I don't want to refresh,it's like the servler,it had better not close and refresh,is there any suggestion?

Comment: If you're running the server in development and uploading files to the MyEclipse workspace project folder then there is no way to avoid the refresh, I'm afraid. I don't really understand why you're doing that, so can't make any suggestions.

Comment: thanks i want to use what people upload to play video,so the files is stored in the project's path,so if don't use myeclipse,don't it can avoid the refresh?

Comment: Deploy the MyEclipse project to a server. Close MyEclipse. Run the server. Your application will be then running on the server, outside of MyEclipse. Ensure that uploaded files are placed in a folder that you can access from the file explorer of the OS (e.g. Windows Explorer - not Internet Explorer). Then you can treat the file like any other file in the file system, including playing any video files. MyEclipse is a development environment; it's not intended to be used to run the completed software.